# non-jquery css animation on page-load and page-unload/exit-page

Tags: css, animation

Is there **a non-jquery way** to have a purely css based animation run on page load and another animation run on page-unload/exit-page?

Comment: What do you mean by page-unload/exit-page?

Comment: Like the following IE meta tags, but with CSS:

<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(Duration=2)">

<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(Duration=2)">

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you're using or the code you've tried to use in the question. I know you can run css animations when the page loads, but I doubt you'll be able to run them when the page exits without some script. Also users may be irritated at having to wait for an animation to run when trying to navigate away from a page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not have any particular animations in mind, but there are some examples at the following URL: http://daneden.me/animate/ 

I think, for example, about a div with a quote that fades in when the html page loads, and when clicking or tapping the quote, the div fades away. Fading in comes the next quote and so on... I do not think of it as being irritating, if the one fades out quickly and the other fades in quickly.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood what you were after. I thought you were trying to get entire pages to animate in and out when you were navigating through a site. I was picturing someone hitting a link and having to wait for an animation before they went to the next page.

Comment: Are we using 'jquery' as a synonym for 'javascript'?

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions! I stick to jQuery, then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations on load can be done with css alone, but for animations on click I think you'll need a little jQuery.

Are you looking for something like this? -[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUNED/2/)

```
$('#container').click(function () {
    $('#container').fadeOut();
    $('#quote1').fadeIn().addClass('bounceInLeft');
});

$('#quote1').click(function () {
    $('#quote1').fadeOut();
    $('#quote2').fadeIn().addClass('bounceInRight');
});
```

You Can also do hover triggered animations in css alone. To connect two or more elements I think that they have to be nested. As in hover over parent, animate child.

Comment: Fade out “on-click” could be achieved if the content that gets faded in on page load is a link pointing to a position inside the document, f.e. the `id` value of the `body` element, `<a id="foo" href="#body">…</a>` – and then the selector `#body:target #foo` would be used to trigger the fade-out of the descendant `a` element …

Comment: @CBroe I hadn't thought of that, I think that may be exactly what the OP is looking for, post it as an answer.

Comment: @CBroe: Good solution, except for the jQuery part. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions! I stick to jQuery, then!

Answer (score 0):

Fade out “on-click” could be achieved if the content that gets faded in on page load is a link pointing to a position inside the document, f.e. the `id` value of the `body` element, `<a id="foo" href="#body">…</a>` – and then the selector `#body:target #foo` would be used to trigger the fade-out of the descendant `a` element …